# Where can I find the web.config in the Azure portal?

Tags: azure, flask, web-config

Every guide that I see say to do something with the web.config file in Azure. However, no matter how much I Google, there is nowhere to be found the steps that I need to take to find the web.config file. Your help will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: What web.config are you looking for? Web apps, specifically, will have a web.config. This isn't something you'd find through the portal though, as it would be part of your own app's deployment. And, depending on the app you're building, you might have to create that file.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few scenarios here. First: when you run on an App Service there *is* a `web.config` file. As David Makagon said, it's not accessible through the portal. By default, app services have [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) available. One of the things this gives you is something like a file explorer. To access Kudu for an App Service with URL `https://someapp.azurewebsites.net`, go to `https://someapp.SCM.azurewebsites.net`.

[image: Kudu in action]

A second thing you could do (which is part of Kudu) is use the App Service Editor. This is an online editor that looks very much like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com). Go to `https://someapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev`.

[image: App Service Editor]

The third thing: if you have any settings in your `web.config` that you want to manage without updating the configuration file, have a look at the [Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure). Any setting that's in there *overrides* the setting with the same name in the web.config.